# Get an element that has an ID which starts with some characters using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a node defined by the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="_13:3AVAsa7qVvAprAar19ie8LRorrLEm2g" >asdf</div>
```

I need to get a reference to it without using it's full id like:

```
dojo.byId('_13:*');
```

Is it possible or is there any other ways that could be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [attribute starts-with selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors).

I've never used Dojo, but looking here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/query.html

It seems that you need this:

```
dojo.query('div[id^="_13:"]')
```

That same link also contains examples of other useful selectors at the end of the page.

Comment: how can i pass a dynamic value at the place where i say _13 like i get a array(node) with id,so i pass it like node.id to that

Comment: Your new question doesn't make complete sense to me, but maybe you're after this: `dojo.query('div[id^="' + yourVariableHere + ':"]')`, where `yourVariableHere` contains a string like `_13`.